# what is the third device in the picture from <unix internal>?

Tags: unix

[image: unix kernel process and device]

The picture above is from the book .

The first device is disk, the second and fifth are monitor and keyborad, the fourth is tape,but what is the third ? It is too old for me ,can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2):

It is a printer a peripheral device which needs driver.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a printer, more specifically, try searching for images of an "impact printer". They looked quite similar. Also, present laser printers designed for use in office environments also look like this, especially if they have scanners/etc also included in the same box.